# Выполнить конкретный скрипт после загрузки ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

Есть такой код:

```
var artAjaxRequest = new function ()
{
  var xhr;

  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', '/assets/json/arts.json', true);
  xhr.send();

  xhr.onload = function(){
    // Тут мы парсим json и формируем массив картинок
  }

  this.getNewArts = function(){
    // Эта функция занимается тем, что выводит картинки на страницу
  };
}();
```

Исполняется это всё "хозяйство" через `artAjaxRequest.getNewArts();`.
Но есть тут проблема: когда я пишу где-то в коде `artAjaxRequest.getNewArts();`, выполняется код `getNewArts`, тогда как сам json ещё не "прилетел" и функция `onload` не отработала своё. Почему? Потому что ajax-запрос не выполняется так быстро, как с кодом разбирается браузер.
Соответственно, json не распарсен и в функции `getNewArts` возникают ошибки.
И вот вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы `.getNewArts` выполнялась после того, как отработает `xhr.onload`?
Но не спешите помещать `artAjaxRequest.getNewArts();` внутрь `onload`. Загвозка в том, что метод `getNewArts()` будет вызываться часто, а **не** один единственный раз, когда прилетает json.
Буду благодарен за разъяснения и советоы по улучшению композиции кода.

Comment: @vp_arth, что значит откуда? Не понял. При чем тут браузер ФФ?

Comment: @vp_arth, ну событий-то много, [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest#итого)  можешь глянуть сам.

Comment: `не спешите помещать artAjaxRequest.getNewArts(); внутрь onload` Непонятно, почему нет.

Comment: @vp_arth, ниже IE9 не поддерживаются. Но кому будет не наплевать на IE9 в 2017-м году - вот в чем вопрос...

Comment: @vp_arth, я же сказал почему. Прочитай ещё раз, что я написал.

Comment: Прочитал, не понял, что мешает вызывать этот метод столько раз сколько нужно.

Comment: @vp_arth вызвать какой метод? `onload`? Это обработчик. Он срабатывает 1 раз, когда запрос завершается (успешно или нет). Это будет нелогично - парсить json 20 раз. Насчет другого я пояснил в вопросе.

Comment: "метод getNewArts() будет вызываться часто, а не один единственный раз"

Comment: @vp_arth, поэтому нельзя засунуть `getNewArts()` в обработчик `onload`, потому что представь, что `artAjaxRequest.getNewArts();` много раз присутствует в коде при разных условиях. JSON не успеет придти, а код `getNewArts()` будет выполняться (вернее - не будет, ведь будут ошибки, так как json, которого ещё нет, нужно ещё распарсить).

Comment: Ну и вот до кучи, ассоциация http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: @vp_arth, я сейчас накопал про promis'ы... Возможно, это то, что я ищу. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Если правильно понял, то можно завести переменную для сформированного результата в области видимости функции.
Также можно реализовать [паттерн Наблюдатель](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)) для своевременного оповещения о полученных данных.

```
var artAjaxRequest = new function ()
{
  var xhr;

  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', '/assets/json/arts.json', true);
  xhr.send();

  var response;

  var subscribers = [];

  xhr.onload = function(){
    // Тут мы парсим json и формируем массив картинок
    response = parsedJSON;

    // Оповещаем подписчиков
    subscribers.forEach(function(sub) {
      sub();
    });
    subscribers.length = 0;
  }

  this.getNewArts = function(next){
    if (!response) {
      // Подписываемся
      subscribers.push(getNewArts.bind(this, next));
      return;
    }
    // Эта функция занимается тем, что выводит картинки на страницу
    next(something)
  };
}();
```

Comment: Прекрасное решение(нет :D). Это первое, что я сделал. Кстати, сразу скажу, что эта переменная уже есть. Но погоды это не делает. Потому что скрипт как выполняется при асинхронном запросе? Выполняется тупо напрямик после `xhr.send()`. Если в коде где-то встречается `artAjaxRequest.getNewArts();`(имею ввиду за пределом этой функции, просто используется где-то), то что вернет функция `getNewArts()`? Ничего. А надо, чтобы отрабатывала свое. Как выполнять `getNewArts()` после того, как придет ответ от `onload`? Это и есть мой вопрос.

Comment: Ну тогда у вас дубликат, батенька) Сейчас найду)

Comment: Я думаю ты найдешь совет Утки про `onload`. Если так, то я буду с пеной у рта добиваться отмены дубликата и потом конкурс сделаю, а администрации пожалуюсь на это. Вот так вот.

Comment: Ничего плохого в вопросе-дубликате нет. Просто решение этой проблемы уже есть в другом вопросе. Дословно ваш вопрос звучит как `"Как вернуть результат асинхронной функции?"`

Comment: Нет. Как вернуть результат асинхронной функции - легко. Вопрос в другом. Как выполнять функцию после асинхронной функции, но чтобы сам вызов этой функции не игнорировался при неготовности асинхронной функции, а выполнялся как она будет уже готова. Короче мне не нужно писать в `getNewArts()` `return;`, потому что мне нужно, чтобы она отработала своё, а не выполнилась как заглушка. Нужно что-то `eventListner`, но не на объект DOM, а  на переменную `xhr.status` (которая говорит о завершении запроса).

Comment: Да ну это тупой код, ты же сам понимаешь это. Даже постыдился бы такое предлагать, ну. Не буду я таймаутами пользоваться.

Comment: А с чего ты взял, что мне нужно ждать каждые 50 милисекунд? Может 25? Или 14? Нет, это нерациональный код и для собственного проекта такое делать не стану. Тут можно и попотеть.

Comment: Окей, добавил в ответ Observer

Comment: Слушай, а второе решение вполне себе. Я думаю даже, что оно сработает как надо. Правда я всё равно промисы дочитаю завтра,  может они лучше подойдут. И пример оригинальный с подписчиками) Единственное, что не понятно, так это как ты это называл - Observer. Я не так давно нагонялся с MutationObserver, который через пень-колоду работает в FF, его напоминает, я думал ты через него сделал (что невозможно, ведь он следит за ДОМ). А по сути это обычный массив с bind, который будет прогонен после загрузки json (что, в принципе, за решение сойдет). Но я попозже его отмечу как решение. Пока не уверен.

Comment: Шаблоны проектирования такие шаблоны... Сделал ссылку на почитать.